# Weird compound-list of dd commands in bash

Tags: bash, dd

I just ran across the following bash construct, I understand this is called compound-list and that those three cat commands are executed in a subshell environment, what I do not get is how the pipes fit in there and more generally, how it works. I would really appreciate a step by step explanation.

It is part of a binary image generation script so I kindof know alreayd what it does, what I do not get is how it gets there:

```
export DD="dd status=noxfer bs=1k iflag=fullblock"
(
    cat $DIR/file1 /dev/zero | $DD count=128
    cat $DIR/file2 /dev/zero | $DD count=128
    cat $DIR/file3 /dev/zero
) | $DD of=$OUT_FILE count=$SIZE
```

Some bash guru out there can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is trying to concatenate all three files into one with padding.  The first cat gets the file plus /dev/zero, padded to 128 kilobytes.  Same with the second, and the third is just cat'ed directly (with /dev/zero also).  Then the pipe takes the output of all three and saves to a file of size $SIZE.  This creates a single file with file1 in a 128 kilobyte block, then file2 in another 128 kilobyte block, then file3 filling the rest with padding.

Comment: This would also be my reading of this. But you were faster than me ;-)

Comment: They are padded to 128KB. Note the bs=1k parameter.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I missed that.  The other options were in my mind because I specifically looked them up, but because I use that one all the time it kind of slipped.

Answer (score 0):

The command `cat` con**cat**enates all the files that are given as arguments.
So:

```
cat $DIR/file1 /dev/zero
```

concatenates `file1` with zero(s) from `/dev/zero` until the following command is willing to read. The next command (in the pipe `|`) is `$DD count=128`, which means that 128 `1k blocks` (note the bs=1k in the definition of the variable) will be read and written to stdout.

In short: read `file1` and pad it with zeros up to 128k.

The next command line is quite similar:

read `file2` and pad it with zeros up to 128k.

And the last line just reads the `file3` (with no padding).

Then, all that (inside parentheses) concatenated stream is given back to `dd` to write to `$OUT_FILE` up to `$SIZE` kbytes.

In short:

```
read all from file1 and pad with zeros up to 128k.
read all from file2 and pad with zeros up to 128k.
read all from file3.
```

Then:

```
Write all that was read to `$OUT_FILE` up to `$SIZE` kBytes.
```